# How to return View to ajax request in MVC?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

if i have a simple partial view:

```
    @if (Model != null)
{
    if (Model.Count() != 0)
    {
        foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <li class="list-group-item list-group-item-success">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-4">@item.FullName</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4">@Resource.Price @item.SalesPrice</div>
                    <div class="col-lg-4"><div class="pull-right"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove remove-glyph" aria-hidden="true"></span></div></div>
                </div>
            </li>
        }
    }
}
```

controller code :

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProductList(List<ProductViewModel> collection)
{

    return  PartialView("_ProductList", collection);
}
```

And my ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url: actionUrl,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: 'json, html',
    cache: false,
    data: JSON.stringify({ collection: temporarySelectedItems }),
    type: 'POST',
    traditional: true
}).done(function (data) {
    console.log(data)
});
```

I can see that my items are serialized nicely, but .done never returns any html.

Comment: Why is your `dataType` expecting `json` when you're actually returning `html`?

Comment: You can simply omit the `dataType` and jQuery will figure it out automatically so even if you *will* return JSON sometime, your `data` argument will be deserialized accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

The ajax call looks fine.  Just modify your controller to return a json result.

```
    [HttpPost()]
    public JsonResult ProductList(List<ProductViewModel> collection)
    {
        //Do something

        return Json(something);
    }
```

You should also use JSON.NET if you are not already.  It is great for taking the pain out of serialization/deserialization of JSON.